# revolution is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having this issue trying to post a data via jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#languageswitcher").change(function() {
    var locale = $(this).val();
    var _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/language",
      type: "POST",
      data: (locale: locale, _token: _token),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      Error: function(data) {
        console.log("error");
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        console.log(locale);
      },
      complete: function(data) {
        console.log("yes");
        window.location.reload(true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<select name="locale" id="languageswitcher">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="zh">Chinese</option>
</select>
```

It displays an error:

> Uncaught Typeerror : Jquery()revolution is not a function

I included the latest jQuery library at the top of my HTML code. However it's still not working. This is the jQuery library I'm using:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

What can be the issue here? I have seen previous related questions but none of them were answered correctly.

Comment: The error seems unrelated to the code you've posted. From the error it sounds like you're attempting to use a library that you haven't included in the page properly, as `revolution()` is not a standard jQuery method. Also note that in your AJAX call, `Error` should be `error` and `data` should be an object. If you check the console I'd guess you have a few errors listed which need to be addressed.

Comment: or in case if you have loaded everything properly, it is "jquery" not "jsquery"

Comment: Ha sorry thanks for Typo correction